# how to know the memory footprint of my binary executable

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, openwrt

I wonder if there is a way to know the memory footprint of my binary executable coded in C language.

> **informations about binary executable** : compiled with toolchain of  OpenWrt branch (Attitude Adjustment) and its architecture is x86

Comment: Do you want to know it's static memory size or it's memory usage during execution?

Comment: if it is possible during execution  ? why not

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On a Linux/Unix system, you can use the [`size`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/size) command for this, e.g. on my Ubuntu system

```
size /bin/sh
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 102134    1776   11272  115182   1c1ee /bin/sh
```

Since this is OpenWrt, if you have a different architecture, e.g. MIPS or ARM or something else, you must pick the `size` command of the appropriate toolchain, of course.

The sections have the following meaning

- `text` denotes the code size of the executable
- `data` is initialized data section, e.g. variables, like `int v = 17;` or `char name[] = "Tom";`
- `bss` is the uninitialized or simply `0` initiailized section, `int a;` or `double amount;`
- `dec` is the overall size, in this case `102134 + 1776 + 11272 = 115182`
- `hex` finally is also the overall size, as a hex value `1c1ee = 115182`

But this does not include the stack or any dynamic heap memory. To see the overall memory usage at runtime, you must look at [`ps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) or [`top`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) output.

Comment: could you explain more the meaning of each parameter (text;    data;     bss;     dec;     hex;)

Comment: Are you sure that it works with C program ? I tryed to do `size path/to/program.c` and I get the error "unkonw format"

Comment: @Bastienm No, this works with binary objects only. So when you compile the C source, e.g. `gcc -c path/to/program.c` you can get the size with `size path/to/program.o`.

Comment: I just understood I had to use it with the binary sorry... Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

To understand your memory usage during runtime, on a Linux system you can use [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/)'s [`memcheck`](http://www.valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck) tool.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Command `size <binary>` to get the memory footprint of your binary executable.
Check the size manual (`man size`) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
top
```

and advanced one called

```
htop
```

are the tools to monitor any executable runing in linux system