# Retrieve memory and cache misses: executables and scripts

Tags: python, bash, perl, caching, profiling

I need to find something theoretically easy, but practically tricky.

Having a bunch of tools under OSX, some are:

- **precompiled java** jars,
- **precompiled** executables which can spawn and call other programs,
- **bash/python/perl scripts** that call some precompiled executables,

I need to **find and classify memory and cache events**. By precompiled I mean, I don't have access to source codes.

In details I'd need to find out the *overall* occupied memory, page faults and virtual memory events, but more importantly, **L1/L2/L3 cache misses**. This means that I need to track all the spawned processes as well, not just the main program.

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: I do not know OSX, but on the systems I know (Windows, Linux or FreeBSD) I would search among the standard monitoring tools. I think they should meet the greatest part of your requirement. Then I would look in system libraries for what would still remains...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should use Valgrind. To have a full report of memory usage:

```
valgrind --tool=massif --stacks=yes
```

This will give you both the heap and stack memory usage. Then the information are stored in the file massif.out.???? that you can read with

ms_print massif.out.?????

I already wrote a post on this: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609797/memory-profiling-for-c-program/33611148#33611148)

Valgrind also records cache events, it gives you the cache misses and a full detailed output of cache events:

```
valgrind --tool=cachegrind prog
```

And then as for the massif you have a tool to read the detailed output:

```
cg_annotate <filename>
```

Refer to the full [documentation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html) to understand the output. 
The option --trace-children=yes permits to profile spawned child